# getting space separated input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get space separated inputs. while the first method works completely fine, the second method throws an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

what is wrong with the second method?

#### Method 1:

```
x = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
```

#### Method 2:

```
x = [j for j in int(input().split())]
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Since you apply `split` to a `str` you get a list, which you feed to `int`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `split()` to a `string` which will return a `list`, then you are passing this `list` to `int()` that's why you are getting error. for changing `datatype` of `list` you need to use `map()` as below or first approach of your's.

Try Below code

```
x = [j for j in map(int,input().split())]
```